# Looking for an app which simplify multilevel inventory using shopify

Tags: shopify, barcode-scanner, inventory, multi-level, barcode-printing

I have described requirement flow using diagram http://creately.com/diagram/example/ifrthu1k1/Flow. I need help in figuring out which app helps in fulfilling my requirements.

In brief my requirement goes like this:

1. Our system contain multiple cities
2. Each cities can have one or more Central Distributed Center (CDC)
3. Each CDC will have one more Districuted Center(DC)
4. Each DC will serve customers belong to one or more regions identified by Zipcodes.
5. Each DC will have some set of products.
6. product mangement in inventory is done using barcode scans. (Good to have feature)
7. Inventory(for DC) planning - which product sold more/less. (Good to have feature)
8. Easily diffrentiate expired product.(Good to have feature)

Comment: take a look at https://apps.shopify.com/shopidrop

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a cart before the horse situation. What you really need is some sort of fulfillment management system. Usually this is part of your ERP (something like Intacct, Netsuite, or SAP) but for smaller businesses with fulfillment being handled by a 3PL you might need to integrate orders with that instead. Once you have a fulfillment management system in place you can integrate that with Shopify via the Shopify API to update Shopify's inventory and allocate Shopify Orders to the appropriate fulfillment center.

So the steps would be:

1. decide how you are going to manage the accounting and fulfillment side of your business.
2. Integrate that system with Shopify.